# How to connect to MySQL database from a different computer?

Tags: java, mysql, database, networking

So I haven successfully set up a database in MySQL and can connect to it from the same laptop I set it up on with a small java program. This is fine as it is running on the local host. However, I would like to see if I could now connect to the same database from a different Laptop. The Laptops would be running on the same network.

I can only find information online about connecting with Local host and am starting to feel out of my depth.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [MYSQL tutorial](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely)

- **Get your IP address**: first You need to know what the IP address you are connecting from.
- **Granting Access**: Granting access to a user from a remote host is fairly simple and can be accomplished from just a few steps. First you will need to login to your MySQL server as the root user.

For **Linux** ([check this site for windows](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/09/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-server-on-windows/)) you can do this by typing the following command:

```
 # mysql -u root -p
 mysql> GRANT ALL ON fooDatabase.* TO fooUser@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
```

Now you can test your connection remotely. You can access your MySQL server from another server by placing the `IP` instead of `localhost`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Check all non-java related system properties, like firewall etc.
2. Test with a general MySQL client.
3. Replace `localhost` or whatever you have in the connection string with the host name or ip-address of the remote machine.
4. Google for `jdbc connection string` to find more examples.

EDIT: If you could show your current code, we may be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Another option without exposing your database to network and defining remote users, is to set up an ssh tunnel. You redirect one port on remote machine to mysql's local port and connect to your database like you were connecting on localhost.

Putty is a popular ssh client. For an ssh server, there are different setups based on your operating system where mysql resides.